# switch TOP clause between percentage and rows by parameter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, dynamic-sql, parameter

For one report I am making query where users suppose have to choice TOP values based on percents or fix amount of rows.

I have two ideas

Calling two different sub stored procedure based on passed param.

```
if @param ='percent'
begin
      exec sp_data_TOP_by_Percent
end
if @param ='perRow'
begin
    exec sp_data_TOP_by_PerRow
end
```

other idea is to make dynamic TSQL query something like this

```
declare @command nchar(max)

select @command = 'select top(10) '
                   + case @param 
                              when 'percent' then percent 
                              else ' '
                     end
                   + ' * '
                   + 'from table 
                        order by 1';
exec sp_executesql @command
```

Is there third solution for something like this ?
What is better approach ?
First one avoiding dynamic TSQL but is harder to maintain code in two places.
I am using MSSQL2005 as databse.

Comment: I'd certainly go with @gbn's route of two procedures. A "helper" procedure wrapping other calls *feels* wrong but its a perfectly acceptable approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd have 2 separate queries/stored procedures just to avoid dynamic SQL.

An IF statement in one stored proc would be enough too

Answer (score 4):

To elaborate on [gbn's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7339/switch-top-clause-between-percentage-and-rows-by-parameter/7340#7340), two stored procedures is the better way to go here; additionally, I'd go one step further and place the query (sans `top` clause) in a [table-valued function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165.aspx) and then have the stored procedures be nothing more than a shell which calls the TVF and applies the `top` clause appropriately (by number of rows or percent).

The only caveat here being that if you use a TVF, try and make sure that it's an [inlined TVF, as it allows the query analyzer to use statistics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554333/multi-statement-table-valued-function-vs-inline-table-valued-function/2554544#2554544) (much like it would a view).